# Disk gets full during file write. How can I get notified about this?

Tags: c++, fstream

I have a quite big object to serialize to disk, like this:

```
if (!EngineFile.empty())
{
    std::ofstream OutEngineStream(EngineFile);
    if (!OutEngineStream)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to write to file \"" << EngineFile << "\"! Aborting ..." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    engine->serialize(OutEngineStream);
    OutEngineStream.close();

    std::cout << "\"" << EngineFile << "\" successfully wrote to disk." << std::endl;
}
```

The problem is, somtimes `serialize` requires larger disk space than available. e.g. there is only 30M storage available but `serialize` requires 200M. In this case I can normally `open` the stream. During `serialize` everything goes well, and `close` returns nothing. The program runs well, but there is only a 30M file on the disk.

How can I get to know about this case?

Comment: Did you mean [GetDiskFreeSpaceEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364937(VS.85).aspx)?

Comment: for windows you can use what @CodeDreamer said above, and for linux you'd better use [statvfs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/statvfs.2.html)  prior to write something to your disk

Comment: You can check the bad bit `OutEngineStream.bad()` to see if there was an error on the iostream.

Comment: Always check for errors. Use [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/Main_Page) to tell you how function calls report errors.

Comment: Typically `std::strerror(errno))` immediately after failure should contain a useful(ish) message.

Comment: @CodeDreamer @lsbbo I do not know how many space will the `serialize` require, so may be checking for error after operation is a better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `serialize` should constantly verify whether its write operations succeed and throw should they fail.

In the code you've presented you should check [`OutEngineStream.fail()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/fail) (it covers more cases than `bad`) before calling `close` (because `close` may also set this state). This however will still leave `serialize` implemented incorrectly.

Comment: Also note that while the table at cppreference.com indicates that `fail()` doesn't include eofbit, that's only technically true. Because the failbit is set by the EOF checking in the iostream sentry object. See e.g. C++11 §27.7.2.1.3/2, "If is.rdbuf()->sbumpc()
or is.rdbuf()->sgetc() returns traits::eof(), the function calls setstate(failbit | eofbit"

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Didn't see your previous comment. Indeed fail is more general, probably I was not focused enough when I was reading cppreference before - only now I see that it explicitly says that if badbit is set then fail will also return true. Also, this of course seems better in this case so my remark about being "more specific" was a nonsense.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Thanks for helping in improving my answer :) Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The presented code checks for failure of opening the file.

In addition it should for failure of the write operation.

That's how to detect if the write operation failed.

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
std::fstream file;
file.exceptions( std::fstream::failbit | std::fstream::badbit );
try {
    // do work
}
catch (std::fstream::failure e) {
    std::cerr << "Exception opening/reading/writing/closing file\n";
}
```

Comment: This is not a good idea. Encountering EOF can throw. The exception throwing feature of iostreams (as much else about iostreams) is just completely botched – Don't Ever Use That Evil Stuff™!