# catching an error for insufficient memory bad_alloc() in an infinite loop in C++ on linux

Tags: c++, linux, exception, infinite-loop, bad-alloc

so i have an infinite loop with an fstream inside that looks more or less like this :

```
int main(){
    while(1){
    StringData() 
    //above is a function with fstream that writes data into a new file    
    return 0;
}
```

The CSV file is written on a USB stick. I want to foresee that the programm will exceed the memory capacity of the USB stick and catch an error that will occur.

I read somewhere that it would throw **bad_alloc()** as it happens, and my idea is to add **try()** and **catch()** for the loop and exit the program totally as the error comes.

Im not even sure if it's the exact error that would appear. Can someone help me with the catching exception?

Thank you and have a good one!

Comment: I really hope your code looks nothing like that.  Write some working code and then catch any exception thrown and test your code on the smallest stick you have access to.

Comment: possible duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40056884/disk-gets-full-during-file-write-how-can-i-get-notified-about-this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disk gets full during file write. How can I get notified about this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40056884/disk-gets-full-during-file-write-how-can-i-get-notified-about-this)

Answer (score 2):

In this case the USB stick is being treated as a disk, so will fail with out of space errors, rather than as memory.

fstream will throw std::ifstream::failure when it can't write anything more to the disk. (Controlled by the exception mask).